# ConnectionError occurred. Project is connected with Telegram Bot API

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection 
aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'Подключение не установлено, т.к. 
конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение', None, 10061, None)),)
```

The project is connected with Telegram Bot API. Does anybody know where the problem is?

Bot needs to ask a user about a game which he wants to play: Hangman or TicTacToe (they are other files with them). User answers and the game needs to start, but I don't receive anything from my bot. I started to work with Telegram a few weeks ago, so I'm pretty new to it.

Code:

```
import telebot
import constants

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["start"])
def start(m):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Hangman', 'Tic Tac Toe']])
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'What do you choose?',
        reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, name)

def name(m):
    if m.text == 'Hangman':
        import hangman
        hangman
    elif m.text == 'Tic Tac Toe':
        import TicTacToe
        TicTacToe

bot.polling()
```

Hangman code is:

```
PICS = ['''

  _____
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
~~~~~~~~''','''

  _____
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
~~~~~~~~''','''

  _____
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
~~~~~~~~''','''

  _____
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
~~~~~~~~''','''

  _____
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
~~~~~~~~''','''

  _____
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
~~~~~~~~''','''

  _____
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
~~~~~~~~''']

keywords = 'lyceum human king guitar music chair case pencil table memes book apple phone computer program boulevard dream university physics mathematics algebra analysis geometry chemistry biology decision property grammar hedgehog progress'.split()

import random

def Random(list):
    i = random.randint(0, len(list) - 1)
    return list[i]

def Again():
        print('Again? (yes/no)')
        inp = input().lower()
        if inp == 'yes':
            return True
        else:
            return False

def Info(PICS, wrong, right, keyword):
    print(PICS[len(wrong)])
    print()
    print('Wrong letters:', end=' ')
    for letter in wrong:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()
    print('Word:', end = ' ')
    star = '*' * len(keyword)
    for j in range(len(keyword)):
        if keyword[j] in right:
            star = star[:j] + keyword[j] + star[j+1:]
    for letter in star:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def Done(doneword):
    while True:
        print('Put a letter:')
        word = input().lower()
        if word in doneword:
            print ('You have tried this one. Choose another letter')
        elif word not in 'mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq':
            print('Please, put a small latin letter')
        elif len(word) != 1:
            print('Your letter:')
        else:
            return word


#start
right = ''
wrong = ''
keyword = Random(keywords)
end = False
while True:
    Info(PICS, wrong, right, keyword)
    word = Done(wrong + right)
    if word in keyword:
        right = right + word
        all = True
        for a in range(len(keyword)):
            if keyword[a] not in right:
                all = False
                break
        if all:
            print('Win!')
            end = True
    else:
        wrong = wrong + word
        if len(wrong) == len(PICS) - 1:
            Info(PICS, wrong, right, keyword)
            print('You lose. Keyword:'+keyword+'"')
            end = True
    if end:
        if Again():
            wrong = ''
            right = ''
            end = False
            keyword = Random(keywords)
        else:
            break
```

There aren`t any errors with games, only with bot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
   body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 204, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
raise err
  File "C:\Users\Соня\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 78, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
```

Comment: Add your code for `hangman` and `TicTacToe` plz. And a full error traceback - to see from with function error comes.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)

Comment: Not in comments. Add this to the question

Comment: ok, that's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TicTacToe` and `hangman` are functions then you need to call them like so `TicTacToe()` and `hangman()`

If they are classes with functions in them then the syntax is a little different, but it is hard to tell without posting those modules

It would be helpful to post those modules.

On another note, as per python's PEP 8 styling guide - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Comment: No, they are files, which I call with `import hangman` and `import TicTacToe`.
When I put `import` at the top of the file, it didn`t work at all

Comment: 1. `import hangman` runs the code in `hangman` that's why it didn't work on top since you didn't want it to be run then. 2. The line `hangman` after `import hangman` has no affect. 3. If you have no functions or classes in hangman then I'm not sure why it's not working since `import hangman` should run the code, but if you have functions or classes then they only get registered with the line `import` but not run, until you call them with `()` like so `hangman()`. Can you please post the code from one of them or both?

Comment: I`ve posted higher

Comment: 8: avito 55.794673